# PowerShell BeginInvoke - PSInvocationSettings not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following c# code for calling powershell using BeginInvoke. I have the following requirements:
- Eventhandlers for "live" streaming of the output, verbose and error streams
- I need to be able to inject an `ErrorActionPreference` when executing the script

My code looks as follows (`powershellScriptSettings.StopOnErrors` is always bool `true`):

```
powershellSettings.ErrorActionPreference = powershellScriptSettings.StopOnErrors ? ActionPreference.Stop : ActionPreference.Continue;

IAsyncResult async = powerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output, powershellSettings, null, null);

//wait for it to complete
try
{
    powerShellInstance.EndInvoke(async);
}
```

Looking at the output stream, I can see that this code executes both write-error commands and that the value of $ErrorActionPreference is at its default (`Continue`):

```
$ErrorActionPreference
Write-error 'err1'
Write-Error 'err2'
```

So it's fairly obvious that my `powershellSettings` are not having an effect. I know I can just add the string `$ErrorActionPreference=Stop` to the beginning of my input script, but I kinda want to do it the "C#" way and use the available functionality in the Powershell api.

I'm wondering if my code is faulty due to the fact that I haven't implemented BeginInvoke's callback function - I can't see that I need it as EndInvoke waits for the script to complete anyways.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7a55bf98b2370ab4817ab2533cb67673053ee446/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/PowerShell.cs), seems like the ErrorActionPreference from the PSInvocationSettings object is only ever taken into account when it's in "batch mode" whatever that means.

Comment: wow thanks! I guess I'll just insert errorActionPreference with some good old fashioned string join instead. Thanks!

Comment: powershellInstance.AddStatement() after the last statement may trigger batch mode from what I read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the `PowerShell` class [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7a55bf98b2370ab4817ab2533cb67673053ee446/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/PowerShell.cs).

If you search through the source code, you'll find that the `ErrorActionPreference` property is only being honored when running in "batch mode".

From looking at the code and tinkering around with the `PowerShell.Commands` property, it seems to me that this simply means that multiple statements have been added to the instance. This kinda makes sense - if there's only one statement to execute then there's no point to trying to figure out whether to continue or not.

You should therefore be able to trigger inspection of the `ErrorActionPreference` property by simply adding an empty statement before executing:

```
powerShellInstance.AddStatement();
IAsyncResult async = powerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output, powershellSettings, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion tho. Even for a script containing a single command the difference between throwing a terminating error or simply exiting gracefully is pretty big - not in terms of how the powershell code itself behaves (as it's finished), but the calling .Net code will have to take extra steps to determine whether the PS script succeeded or not (Such as looking at the "hasErrors" attribute of the result obj.